# Why is cyclooctene the smallest cycloalkene to have cis-trans isomerism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

What prevents cis and trans isomers from existing in smaller cycloalkenes, for example, cyclohexenes for more than a short period of time?

Comment: Try building a model of trans-cyclohexene, a good lesson to understand ring strain

Comment: You might also look at https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo00389a067 which also says trans-cycloheptene has been prepared, but half a half life of ~10 minutes at 274K

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/30940/relative-stability-of-cis-and-trans-cycloalkenes

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78571/why-is-cyclooctateraene-shaped-like-a-tub-rather-than-a-chair cyclooctadiene with two trans bonds was made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether cyclooctene is the lowest such alkene is not cut and dried. *trans*-cycloheptene is known as a transient species (Inoue et al [1](https://doi.org/10.1039/C39810001031) and Verbeek et al. [2](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00389a067)). Calculations indicate that it converts to the more stable *cis* isomer through a diradical intermediate, not a double-bond rotation (Squillacote et al, [3](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja055388i)).

Consider a planar $n$-sided polygon with $n-2$ vertex angles measuring $109.5°$ and the remaining two vertex angles measuring $120°$ and $240°$, the last of these a reflex angle at a concave vertex. Then the sum of angles is both $180°(n-2)$ (from the planar polygon formula) and $109.5°(n-2)+360°$ (from the specified angles), where these expressions closely agree at $n=7$. Thus *trans*-cycloheptene would be forced to have all ring atoms essentially is one plane, which is highly strained for a seven-atom ring with only one double bond (compare with the observed structure of *cis*-cycloalkenes). With an eighth atom in the ring, so that $109.5°(n-2)+360°$ is significantly less than the planar-polygon angle sum $180°(n-2)$, the forced planarity is relaxed and the structure is much less strained.

**References**

1. Yoshihisa Inoue, Toshihiko Ueoka,   Takayuki Kuroda  and  Tadao Hakushi. "trans-Cycloheptene. Photochemical generation and thermal trans-cis isomerization". *J. Chem. Soc., Chem. Commun.*, 1981, 1031-1033. https://doi.org/10.1039/C39810001031.
2. J. Verbeek, J. H. Van Lenthe, P. J. J. A. Timmermans, A. Mackor, and P. H. M. Budzelaar. "On the existence of trans-cyclohexene". *J. Org. Chem.* 1987, **52**, 13, 2955–2957.
   https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00389a067.
3. Michael E. Squillacote, James DeFellipis, and Qingning Shu
   "How Stable Is trans-Cycloheptene?" *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* 2005, **127**, 45, 15983–15988.
   https://doi.org/10.1021/ja055388i